# how show nested relation in laravel resource

Tags: laravel

I have *Category* Model that has **one to many** relation with itself.

It means each category has many children and each child has many products.

Now, I want to show parent categories (it means **parent_id** is null) with all products (list of products of all children).

Each product has **category_id** that category is child.

What is the best way to handle this in Laravel resources?

**Category Model**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Products', 'category_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

My **Query**:

```
$categories = Category::select(['id', 'name'])
            ->where('parent_id', '=', null)
            ->with(['children' => function ($query){
                $query->select(['id']);
                $query->with('products:id,title,description,banner');
            }])
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

And **Resource**:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'category' => $this->name,
            'products' => [],
        ];
    }
```

I tried many different ways to show products, none of them has worked so far.

Comment: can you post one of those ways you tried to show products?

Comment: The [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship provides a convenient way to access distant relations via an intermediate relation.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I tried it already, but I faced with error, now I work more, so it works. thanks

Comment: Ok, so I understand that you managed to fix it. If so, please write an answer with the solution so that it can be of use to other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used **hasManyThrough** relation to get all product of each main category

**Relation function:**

```
public function childrenproducts() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough( Product::class, Category::class , 'parent_id', 'category_id' );
    }
```

**Query:**

```
$categories = Category::select(['id', 'name'])
            ->where('parent_id', '=', null)
            ->has('childrenproducts', '>=', 1)
            ->with(['childrenproducts' => function ($query) {
                $query->select(['products.id', 'products.title', 'products.description', 'products.banner']);
                $query->orderBy('products.id', 'desc');
            }])
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'category' => $this->getName(),
            'products' => ProductResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('childrenproducts'))
        ];
    }
```